# What is this ffmpeg call doing?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
args = {"vf": "thumbnail=100,setpts=N/TB", "r": "1", "vframes": str(max_num_frames)}
stream = ffmpeg.input(input_path)
stream = stream.output(output_format, **args).overwrite_output()
```

I know this code is trying to generate frames from a video file, but what does the args really mean?

In particular, what is the role of "setpts" and "r" ?

Looks like it says get one frame output for every 100 frames, but how exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looks like it says get one frame output for every 100 frames, but how exactly?

[The `thumbnail` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#thumbnail) is responsible for the operation.

> In particular, what is the role of "setpts" and "r" ?

These sets the timing of the output video (1 thumbnail frame per second). The `setpts` filter redefines interval between the thumbnail frames to be one second apart, and the `-r` output option sets the output constant framerate to match the `setpts` interval.